# Angular : Create a service using $http

Tags: angularjs

I try to create a service for my user. I use a request http for get the current user. 
For avoid to call my server each time that I call the userService.getCurrentUser() I tried to send a variable if the request has already be send or call the server if it is the first time.

Here my service :

```
angular.module('UserService', []) 
.factory('UserService', function($q , $http, $rootScope,$timeout) {
    var currentUser = null;

    return {
        getCurrentUser: function() {
                if (currentUser == null){
                var config = {};

                config.cache = true;
                config.method = "GET"; 
                config.url = "users/get_current_user";
            return $http(config)
                .then(function(response) {
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                            currentUser = response.data.user;
                        return response.data.user;
                    } else {
                        // invalid response
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    }

                }, function(response) {
                    // something went wrong
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                });
                }
                else{
                    return currentUser;
                }
        }
        };     
});
```

Unfortunately I call my request few time because the promise is not immediately resolved.
How can I fix this to be sure to call my server once.

And how call this function from my controller because some time the return value is an promise so I use .then() and sometime it will be the value currentUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would need to save (and return in future invocations) is the promise itself. This way, it's guaranteed that:

1. You will always get a promise object from your function (consistent behavior)
2. You will never fire more than one request.

You can achieve this by changing your code as following:

```
angular.module('UserService', []) 
.factory('UserService', function($q , $http, $rootScope,$timeout) {
    var currentUserPromise = null;

    return {
        getCurrentUser: function() {
            if (currentUserPromise === null) {
                var config = {};

                config.cache = true;
                config.method = "GET"; 
                config.url = "users/get_current_user";
                currentUserPromise = $http(config)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                            return response.data.user;
                        } else {
                            // invalid response
                            return $q.reject(response.data);
                        }  
                    }, function(response) {
                        // something went wrong
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    });
            }
            return currentUserPromise;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hello urish, first thx for your answer. Great it works verry well so like it's a promise for get the data in my controller I need to do this : UserService.getCurrentUser().then(function(user){$scope.currentUser = user;}), instead of that $scope.currentUser = UserService.getCurrentUser() ?? it's little be constraining.

Comment: You welcome Flavien! Well, before AngularJS 1.2.0 you could get away with assigning the returned promise directly to the scope and this would work as expected, but since angular 1.2.0-rc3 this is deprecated (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4158) and you should explicitly call .then() in your controller as you mentioned.